# Why filter section is bumped to the bottom?

Tags: angular

Here is the expected display layout, top to bottom:

1. Error msg if any, else hide
2. Filter selection to search for matching records, always shows.
3. List of returned records satisfying filter selection, initially empty.

Template HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="errMsg;else dataOK">Sorry: {{errMsg}}</div>
<div name="Filters">
        Date:
            <input name="datefrom" type="date".../> - 
            <input name="dateto" type="date".../>
    </div>
<button (click)="goSearch()">Search</button>

<ng-template #dataOK>
<div *ngIf="AnyMatchingRecords">
...
</div>
</ng-template>
```

But when there is some matching records returned, actual display is 2 and 3 **swapped**, `#dataOK` on top of `Filters`, and filter section got bumped to the bottom.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using  `ng-template` which act like a replacement over the block evaluated to false by your condition. Since you conditioned block is in first position, then the template is as well when displayed.

Replace your `ng-template` block by a normal one as follow :

```
<div *ngIf="!errMsg">
  <div *ngIf="AnyMatchingRecords">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [small repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ime4kb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to see the difference. here is the code :

html :

```
<div *ngIf="isShown; else notShownContent">
    Is shown content<br />
    <button (click)="doSomething()">Switch condition</button>
</div>
<div>Hello that's a normal content</div>
<ng-template #notShownContent>
    No shown content : I'll replace the first block
</ng-template>

<hr>

<div *ngIf="isShown">
    Is shown content<br />
    <button (click)="doSomething()">Switch condition</button>
</div>
<div>Hello that's a normal content</div>
<div *ngIf="!isShown">
    No shown content : I'll stay at the end of the page
</div>
```

ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  isShown = true;

  doSomething() {
    this.isShown = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You meant the first `<div *ngIf="errMsg;else dataOK">Sorry: {{errMsg}}</div>` is a placeholder for both condition, no matter where `<ng-template #dataOK>` is defined.

Comment: @Jeb50 Yes exactly !